# Rust no_std split_at_mut function "no method named `split_mut_at` found for type" compilation error in rust stable

Tags: rust

I am trying to extract bits of code from an embedded rust example that does not compile. A lot of these old embedded examples don't compile because they use nightly and they quickly become broken and neglected.

```
let mut buffer : [u8; 2048] = [0;2048];
// some code to fill the buffer here
// say we want to split the buffer at position 300
let (request_buffer, response_buffer) = buffer.split_mut_at(300);
```

This example uses `#![no_std]` so there is no standard library to link to and must have compiled at some point so the function split_mut_at must have worked at some point. I am using IntelliJ rust AND Visual Studio Code as the IDE but neither IDE's can point me to the definition of the split_mut_at function. There is a minefield of crates and use statements in the example and there is no clear way to pin-point where some function comes without huge trial and error effort.

btw, split_at_mut can usually be found in `std::string::String`

Is there a rust command that tells you what crate a function belongs to in your project? It always takes so long to update rust-docs when doing a rust update. Surely that can help!

Comment: The function is called `split_at_mut`, not `split_mut_at` (you're using both names interchangeably). The documentation for the libraries shipped with Rust (including `core` and `std`) [is also online](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/). When browsing the documentation, use the search bar to search across all available crates in a documentation set (you can see the crates in the sidebar on the left when looking at a crate's root page). Note that primitive types are special; they're always documented in `std`, even if the methods are provided by `core` (as is the case for slice methods).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Francis, missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `slice::split_at_mut` (note the `mut` at the end). It is listed in the nightly docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) and the stable docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut). It is also indeed available with `#![no_std]`. It is defined in `libcore` [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ad55b73da1e3701cf09c54dc813779adbae39d5b/src/libcore/slice/mod.rs#L966-L1002).

As a general rule of thumb when a function `x` from `core` or `std` has a mutable and immutable variant, the function requiring a immutable reference is named `x` and the function requiring a mutable reference is named `x_mut`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, very useful to know about that naming convention now.